# How to buld a rest ful API with RXJava and Micronaut?

Tags: rest, rx-java2, micronaut

I would like to write a REST API that return HTTP 400 when I try to create an already existing entity or when I try to update an non existing entity.

```
@Post
fun create(@Body entity: @Valid Entity): HttpResponse<Entity> {
    val optional = entityService.find(entity)
    if(optional.isPresent) {
        return HttpResponse.badRequest()
    }
    return HttpResponse.created(entityService.save(entity))
}
```

How can I do that using non blocking endpoint with RXJava2 and Micronaut, I can only find examples with **switchIfEmpty**

```
@Post
@Status(HttpStatus.CREATED)
fun createMeal(@Body entity: @Valid Entity): Single<Entity> {
    return entityService.find(entity)
            .switchIfEmpty(entityService.save(entity))
            .map{success -> entity}
}
```

but this code always return HTTP 200 even if nothing is saved, I don't think it's a good practice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would use `map` to convert the entity to a bad request response since if it exists that is what you want to return. You could also use switchIfEmpty to save the entity which would only occur if the entity is not found. Ensure you wrap that code inside `Flowable.defer` to prevent the logic from executing no matter what. In your reactive example above the save will occur on every execution.

```
return entityService.find(entity)
    .map(entity -> HttpResponse.badRequest())
    .switchIfEmpty(Flowable.defer() -> {
        //return a publisher that emits HttpResponse.created(entity)
    })
```

Comment: I will test your solution later, I'm short this time. Thanks

Comment: Hello I find this way for update :

`entityRepository.find(name)
                .flatMapSingleElement { entityRepository.update(entity) }
                .switchIfEmpty(Single.error<Meal> { RuntimeException("Entityl $name do not exists") })`

But no clue for save

Answer (score 0):

Finally I do something like this :

```
fun update(name: String, entity: Entity): Single<Entity> {
    val observable = BehaviorSubject.create<Entity>()
    entitysRepository.find(name)
            .subscribe(
                    {
                        entity.name = name
                        update(entity, observable)
                    },
                    { observable.onError(RuntimeException("Entity : $name doesn't exist")) }
            )
    return observable.singleOrError()
}

fun save(entity: Entity): Single<Entity> {
    val observable = BehaviorSubject.create<Entity>()
    entitysRepository.find(entity.name)
            .subscribe(
                    { observable.onError(RuntimeException("Entity : ${entity.name} already exist")) },
                    { save(entity, observable) }
            )
    return observable.singleOrError()
}
```

Don't really know if it's a good practice or not.